# Listview or Gridview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-studio, android-gridview

I really confused on what widget should I use to display in my application. First I receive from a Web service 3 vectors:

```
for (int i = 0; i < intPropertyCount; i++) {                        
                        Object property = resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty(i);
                        if (property instanceof SoapObject) {
                            SoapObject DocTypeList = (SoapObject) property;
                            //CedulaUsuario
                            strUserDocument[i] = DocTypeList.getProperty("CedulaUsuario").toString();
                            //Observacion
                            strNeedsDescription[i] = DocTypeList.getProperty("Observacion").toString();
                            //Estado
                            strNeedStatus[i] = DocTypeList.getProperty("Respueta").toString();
                        }
                    }
```

until that is perfect, but I want to show those values in a widget (Listview or gridView), and after tapping an option, do another action; but don't know if ListView or a gridview could be more useful for what I need. This is how I want to display the information I receive from the WS:

```
Document    Description       status  --->Header
123456     Hello, Descr...      Yes
987654     Another Desc...      No 
654987     More, Descri...      Yes
```

Any example, code or link that could help me to achieve this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CustomListView with custom layout,so, you can add and delete new items to the list more easily.

here an example.

http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92

http://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-articles/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android/

Comment: en realidad, no lo es... y normalmente siempre se usa un customListView.... una vez aprendes a hacer el primero, los demas solo es copiar y pegar.